# Ada actual for "S" must be a variable

Tags: ada

So here is a piece of my body file. I am getting the error "words.adb:75:42: actual for "S" must be a variable".

```
procedure Remove_Character(S : in out Ustring; C : in Character; Successful : out Boolean) is
begin
    for I in 1..length(S) loop
        if Element(S, I) = C then
            Delete(S, I, I);
            Successful := true;
            return;
        end if;
    end loop;
    Successful := false;
end Remove_Character;

function Is_Subset(Subset : Ustring; S : Ustring) return Boolean is
Could_Remove : Boolean;
begin
    for I in 1..length(Subset) loop
        Remove_Character(S , Element(Subset, I), Could_Remove);
        if Could_Remove = false then
            return false;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return True;
end Is_Subset;
```

I understand where my error is coming from. Remove_Character uses S : in out Ustring while function Is_Subset uses S : in Ustring.
My question is how do I change the variable from Remove_Character into only an in Ustring?
Sorry if this is a tad jumbled, I'm fairly new to both programming and the site.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, at least not directly.

I don't know what a `UString` is, but I presume the `Delete` procedure modifies it. If you changed the declaration of `S` in `Remove_Character` to `S: in Ustring`, you'd presumably get an error on the call to `Delete`.

The simplest approach I can think of would be to make a copy of `S` in `Is_Subset`:

```
Copy_Of_S: UString := S;
```

and then pass the (modifiable) copy to `Remove_Character`.

By "simplest", I mean it makes the smallest change to your existing code. But you should probably consider reorganizing it. Determining whether one UString is a subset of another by modifying one of the strings doesn't seem like the best approach; I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do it.

A minor and irrelevant point: this:

```
if Could_Remove = false then
```

is better written as:

```
if not Could_Remove then
```

Comment: Keith is right about how to resolve your compilation problem. However, you should think carefully about your loops; `1..length(subset)` is evaluated once at the start of the loop, but you change `length(Subset)` during the loop. You could use a [loop exit statement](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5.html#p15).